# Trying to select item from dropdown box

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to select an item from a drop down list using a variable.
I'm able to click the drop down list, I'm able to click on the item with explicit text but not using a variable.

Chrome (v 75.0.3770.142) using Selenium Basic ChromeDriver (v 75.0.3770.140) in Excel (2013) VBA.

it works if i use explicit:

```
Obj.FindElementByXPath("//option[@label='Z01 - Customer Request - Paid']").Click
```

but doesn't work if using a string variable:

```
Obj.FindElementByXPath("//option[@label=SomeStringVariable]").Click
```

Here's the HTML:

```html
<select id="tickboxreason" name="boxreason" class="emergency-reasons form-control ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-model="currentCartConfig.boxreason" ng-options="reason.displayValue for reason in reasonList.emergencyOrderReasons | orderBy:'code' track by reason.code" ng-change="updateRDD()" ng-required="currentCartConfig.emergencyFlag" required="required">
<option value="">Select Reason</option>
<option value="Z01" label="Z01 - Customer Request - Paid">Z01 - Customer Request - Paid</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the string quotes.Try the below option.

```
Obj.FindElementByXPath("//option[@label='" & SomeStringVariable & "']").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a faster css attribute = value selector

```
obj.FindElementByCss("[label='" & variable & "']").click
```